# Color change of potassium permanganate during a titration with Fe(II)

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, titration, color

Is it possible for potassium permanganate to have color change (in a titration) from colorless to pink? If so, then in what circumstances (particularly for a titration)? I have been always been taught that color change for potassium permanganate is purple/pink to colorless. I have scoured the whole internet searching for an example and I couldn't find one.

The problem is a question in a recent A level paper which asked about the color change of $\ce{KMnO4}$ with an $\ce{Fe^2+}$ solution. The answer was colorless to pink. The examiner report further mentioned that many students wrote purple/pink to colorless, however it was marked incorrect.

Can someone explain the ambiguity here?

Comment: "Potassium manganate", without further disambiguation, usually refers to Mn(VI) $\ce{K2MnO4}$. You need to use either "potassium permanganate" (much more common) or "potassium manganate(VII)".

Answer (score 3):

An aqueous solution of potassium permanganate, $\ce{KMnO4}$ is of purple colour, regardless if the solution is neutral, acidic, or basic.  Potassium permanganate is a relative powerful oxidizer. (As a look-up in a table of standard electrode potentials may tell.) If one considers acidic conditions $\ce{KMnO4}$ may *oxidize* material, like

$$\ce{Fe^{2+} -> Fe^{3+} + e-}$$

while being reduced from oxidation state +7 to oxidation state +2 in the form of $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$.  Aqueous solutions of, say $\ce{MnSO4}$, however are almost colourless.  On the other hand, $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ alone is not a strong oxidizer, under normal conditions incapable to generate permanganate.  That is why this analysis is widely used ([application note](http://www.metrohm.ru/Special/Thermometric/1353160_AN-h128.pdf), [example 1](http://www.lahc.edu/classes/chemistry/arias/exp%208%20-%20redox.pdf), [example 2](http://www.austincc.edu/dsackett/CHEM1412/lab/1412exp28.pdf) in lab classes and beyond).

The *end point* of the redox titration is reached if all $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is oxidized, so that under addition of additional $\ce{KMnO4}$, your analyte solution remains purple.

Comment: But in the provided example of $\rm KMnO_4$ and $\rm Fe^{2+}$, it is not possible for the colour change to be from colourless to pink right (assuming no additional $\rm KMnO_4$ is added)?

Comment: @Faiq You have to add an extra bit of $\ce{KMnO4}$, otherwise you can't tell when the titration is done.

Comment: By observing for the colourless phase. The moment the colour disappears is my endpoint

Comment: @FaiqRaees  During the titration, $\ce{KMnO4}$ is consumed, hence the purple colour of this added reagent solution, added to you analyte of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$, vanishes.  Once all the $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is consumed, the reaction with $\ce{KMnO4}$ is discontinued; hence, further addition of $\ce{KMnO4}$ will *now* yield the persistent purple colouration.